# How to clear fields after post back in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering how do I clear fields after a postback in asp.net mvc? Like right now when validation errors occur the fields stay populated with whatever a user would entered. This is fine however, when no validation errors occur I want the all the fields to clear and a message to display.

So right now I have the success displaying by using ViewData but not sure how to get the fields to clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the [PRG (Post Redirect Get) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) because you don't want the users to refresh the page and have it submit again.

To do this I would put a message or flag in your TempData so that you can inspect that when you redirect back to the original url to then display a message to the user.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
}
return View();
```

Comment: Might also want to set your ModelState errors AFTER this line :)

Comment: Work as a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Phil Haack said:

> Try calling

```
ModelState["value1"].Value = new
ValueProviderResult(null,
string.Empty,
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> before you return the view from within
>   your controller action.
>
> What this does is keep all the errors
>   associated with the key "value1", but
>   replaces the value with an empty
>   value.

[From this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628872/asp-net-mvc-unbind-action-parameter/1640888#1640888)

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the model, new reference when you post back you model in the view.
Something like this.

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Do your stuff here. 

        yourModel = new Moodel();
        return View(yourModel);

    }
```

In this scenario all model fields will be empty and nothing will be displayed at form.